# Facebook meta og tags defined in body ,throwing error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-share, facebook-tag

How can i define Facebook meta og tags?
Facebook is throwing the following error:

> The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly defining the `og:url` meta tag?

Comment: below is the metatag defined in body :

<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xcv" />
<meta property="og:type"   content="dfd:item" />
<meta property="og:description" content="dd" /> 
<meta name="og_title" property="og:title" content="dd"/>
<meta name="og_site_name" property="og:site_name" content="dd.com"/>
<meta name="og_image" property="og:image" content="ddd.png"/>
<meta name="og_url" property="og:url" id="og-url" content="asfasfasfasfas" />

Comment: Tell us the actual URL of the page if you want help, so that we can have a look at the issue ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly defining the `og:url` property *as a property* in your file.

Example:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/mypage"/>
```

Comment: <meta name="og_url" property="og:url" id="og-url" content="http://www.help.com/123" />